# He instalado cuatro veces Anaconda, desde la pagina oficial, claro, y no logro abrirlo....cual sera el problema?

Tags: anaconda, conda, datos

He instalado seis veces Anaconda, desde la pagina oficial, claro, y no logro abrirlo....cual será el problema?

El pc me va muy bien, sin ningún problema.

Necesito instalar Anaconda-navigator, para trabajar en Proyectos de ciencia de datos.

Tengo dos OS: Windows 10 y Ubuntu; no se si eso influye en algo. En los dos tengo el mismo problema:

NO me aparece el "launcher" de Anaconda-navigator, ni de 'conda'....nada. Solo las carpetas, el instalador y el desinstalador.

Alguien sabe cual es el problema, o mejor dicho, algún camino correcto para abrir el programa?

También lo he tratado de iniciar desde el CMD de Windows, y desde la Terminal de Ubuntu, pero es evidente que lo estoy haciendo mal.

Esto veo cuando lo busco abrir en Windows 10, por ejemplo:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de resolver mi pregunta, para los que tengan el mismo problema...

Instalé Anaconda en Windows 10, pero fuera del "user"; es decir, seleccioné en la instalación la opción de "instalar para TODOS los usuarios", así se instala en C:, y no en el usuario.

Cuando termina la instalación, ya aparece en el menú, el sortcut:

[image: anaconda en el menu windows10]

Así, solucionado

[image: instalacion exitosa]